# Crystal Report Subreport create link to array with IDs

Tags: c#, arrays, crystal-reports, subreport

I created a subreport in crystal reports. I can link the subreport with a formula field, a parameter or a field from the database, but I cannot link it to a list or an array of IDs.

The problem here is that the subreport should be created for every single ID that exists in the array and not for only one ID. I tried to add more fields which every single field contains a ID from the array but that doesn't work,

Can anybody help me? It's really important for my work.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't create array of the IDs, Instead create a group with the ID and place the sub report in group footer which will force the sub report to be created for every ID

Comment: My problem is that the IDs are in a string like -> ;2;100;1
and I have to put them into a List or Array that I can link them to the subreport!

Comment: Now I dont have tool will try to post solution tomorrow

Comment: So I tried your suggestion and it works perfectly! I changed the database that the IDs will be saved now in a new datatable and not as a string.

Answer (score 0):

Just follow this .. and you will finish your work . I have a project like yours and I follow this .. just click this link http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/manishkdwivedi/create-a-report-using-crystal-report-in-visual-studio-2010/

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page

{

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

{

    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Server=myserver;uid=sa;pwd=nothing;Database=MyDB;");

    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Select top 10 * From Customers", connection);

    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);

    //Customer _Customer = new Customer();

    DataSet dataset = new DataSet();

    adapter.Fill(dataset, "Customer");

    ReportDocument CustomerReport = new ReportDocument();

    CustomerReport.Load(Server.MapPath("CustomerReport.rpt"));

    CustomerReport.SetDataSource(dataset.Tables["Customer"]);

    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = CustomerReport;

    CrystalReportViewer1.DataBind();

}
```

}